# Haskell Type that Supports Addition and Subtraction Only

Tags: haskell, time, timer

Say I have a type defined like such.

```
data Seconds | Seconds Integer
```

I could define a function for counting down like this.

```
decrementTimer :: Seconds -> Seconds -> Seconds
decrementTimer (Seconds internalSecondsOne) (Seconds internalSecondsTwo) = Seconds $ internalSecondsOne - internalSecondsTwo
```

But that seems tedious and messy, and I'd have to do it for every representation of time; hours, minutes, time periodd data that holds seconds, minutes, and hours.

What I really want to do is "implement"(?) the Num type class, so I can do something like this.

```
decrementTimer :: Seconds -> Seconds -> Seconds
decrementTimer a b = a - b
```

But then wouldn't I need to support multiplication and division? It doesn't really make sense to divide Seconds by Seconds. How would I go about making a type support addition and subtraction? Or if it's impossible or my reasoning is completely wrong, what would be the idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

Comment: First, `Seconds` should be instance of `Monoid`. Second, I think `decreaseTimer :: Seconds -> Seconds -> Maybe Seconds` would be better, because what if in `decreaseTimer a b` `b` is larger than `a` ?  third. you can always write `(<->) = decreaseTimer` introducing new operator (of course finding ascii art not clashing with something from `base` and other hackage packages may be a problem)

Comment: @permeakra I might not know enough Haskell yet, but why would Seconds need to be a Monoid? I've been thinking over what to do if b is larger than a. I've though of Maybe, but I've also thought of just setting the value to zero (no time left) instead. And you're right, finding an unused operator that is still useful is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: 1)Why it should not? Time lengths are obviously summable, and monoid is the proper class for such behaviour. `base` has some fancy staff for monoid instances. 2)That depends on usecase, sometimes setting value to zero would be appropriate, but not always, sometimes explicit failure is better. I believe that for general-purpose type it is better to be safe than sorry and enforce checks on type level whenever possible.

Comment: @permeakra I feel strongly that if you take a larger from a smaller, you should get a negative answer, and if the person using your function doesn't want that, they can check for it and use zero instead, or run some error response code, or whatever's appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're out of luck with the standard prelude, the Num typeclass requires you to implement functions that just don't make sense for this datatype. There are basically three options

1. Name the functions something other than + and -. This is probably the preferred option.
2. Implement the Num typeclass, but have the functions that don't make sense throw an error. This has the downside that it turns what should be a compile-time error into a run-time error.
3. Use a different Prelude, such as the [Numeric Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) that splits the functions from Num out into other type classes. This option is the most mathematically correct, but also kind of inconvenient since it doesn't use the standard Prelude.

Answer (score 3):

First – why not use an existing physical-quantity–library? For instance, [dimensional-tf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-tf). It's kind of strange to limit yourself to seconds, when these are really just one of many possible time units, though the fact that you use `Integer` rather than the more obvious `Double` indicates you're indeed interested in a fixed time-raster, quantised to seconds.

The precise type class for something that can be added and subtracted, but not multiplied, exists: [`AdditiveGroup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-AdditiveGroup.html) in the [`vector-spaces`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) package.

```
instance AdditiveGroup Seconds where
  zeroV = Seconds 0
  Seconds a ^+^ Seconds b = Seconds $ a+b
  negateV (Seconds a) = Seconds $ negate a
```

In fact, you might also define a [vector space](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html) instance:

```
instance VectorSpace Seconds where
  type Scalar Seconds = Integer
  μ *^ (Seconds a) = Seconds $ μ * a
```

Though this doesn't really seem all that useful with the integer quantisation, you'd normally have `type Scalar Seconds = Double` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* make functions named `+` and `-` that work on seconds, but there's no way for it to be the same `+` and `-` from the `Num` type class without making `Seconds` an instance of `Num` (which therefore will lead any code that gets a `Seconds` value as a generic `Num a` to expect that it can use the other `Num` functions as well).

All you have to do is explicitly import the Prelude, either hiding `+` and `-` or importing it qualified.

The trouble then is that any code using your `+` and `-` also has to do something to resolve the ambiguity with the Prelude `+` and `-`; either you only have one version of `+` in scope, or at least one of them must always be referred to with a qualified name (some variant of `Prelude.+`, `P.+`, `S.+`, `Seconds.+`, etc). For an obscure name, this is sometimes acceptable. It's probably not a good idea with something as common and fundamental as `+`.

You could make that option nicer by making `+` and `-` functions in a *new* type class (say `PlusMinus`), and write `instance Num a => PlusMinus a where (+) = (Prelude.+)` etc. You then also make `Seconds` an instance of `PlusMinus`.<sup>1</sup>

What this buys you is that any code that wants to use your new `+` operator can at least safely hide the Prelude's `+` while still being able to use `+` on other `Num` types. It does still impose some bother on every module wanting to use your `+` though, and it has the potential to be confusing (someone one day may see `+` being used on `Seconds` without being deeply familiar with all this, and assume that they can use other numeric operations on `Seconds`).

Probably better would be to make functions that aren't called `+` and `-`. You can use new multi-character operators containing `+` and `-` if you want (though it can be tricky to find ones that aren't used by other libraries).

---

Here's an approach I once took that was sort-of massive overkill, but also sort-of satisfying.

The problem was that I had vectors representing absolute positions, and also vectors representing offsets. I decided it made sense to add and subtract offsets, but not positions. However it did make sense to add an offset to a position to get a position, or to subtract two positions to get an offset, and even to multiply an offset by a scalar to get an offset.

So what I ended up doing was to define a type class something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies #-}

class Addable a b where
    type Result a
    (|+|) :: a -> b -> Result a b

instance Addable Offset Offset where
    type Result Offset Offset = Offset
    o |+| o = ...

instance Addable Position Offset where
    type Result Position Offset = Position
    p |+| o = ...

instance Addable Offset Position where
    type Result Offset Position = Position
    o |+| p = p |+| o
```

etc

So you end up using `|+|` rather than `+`, but it still ends up looking a bit like the algebra you're used to thinking in (once you get used to the convention that `|+|` is the "generalised" version of `+`, etc), and it lets you encode a lot of rules about what operations make sense in the type system, so the compiler can check them for you. The downside is a lot of boilerplate defining all the instances, but for a small fixed number of types that's something you only have to do once.

---

<sup>1</sup>You'll need extensions to make this work; it's a little unsafe in principle because there could be an instance of `Num` for `Seconds` out there somewhere, which would make `Seconds` match `PlusMinus` two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the operations on a data type, the standard trick is to not export the constructor for your type. That way functions dont have access to the internals of the data, and can only use the operations you provide. So you'd want something like:

```
module Seconds (Seconds) where

newtype Seconds = Seconds Integer

mkSeconds  :: Integer -> Seconds
addSeconds :: Seconds -> Seconds -> Seconds
subSeconds :: Seconds -> Seconds -> Seconds
```

note that the module exports `Seconds`, not `Seconds(..)`, so the **type** `Seconds` is available, but the **constructor** is not. Now it's impossible to write a function

```
dangerousMult :: Seconds -> Seconds -> Seconds
dangerousMult (Seconds i) (Seconds j) = Seconds (i * j)
```

Comment: So the user can still make type signatures for their own functions that use Seconds because they have the type constructor, but they don't have the concrete type, so they can't construct a Seconds datum without using my constructor function? Also, I take it that it's not possible to use the '+' and '-' functions directly?

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately you cant, but you might be able to seperate anything requiring your provided `Seconds` functions into a module, hide `Prelude.(+)/(-)` and rename your functions.